# How can I display detailViewController in didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing, push-notification

My scenario, I have an app that have three tabs. Each tabs have a tableViewController. And when you tap on tableViewCell the detail view controller will be showing up and I set webview for detail view controller. My question is, how can I display detail view controller when users tap on push notification when app is running and inactive.

This is my code for application:didReceiveRemoteNotification method :

```
// Set the view to HotTableViewController when user tapped on remote notification
    UIStoryboard *ab = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    HotTableViewController *hotArticle = [ab instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hotArticle"]; //hotArticle identifier is detailVC id name
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
//    tabController.selectedIndex = 0;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)tabController.selectedViewController;
    [navigationController pushViewController:hotArticle animated:YES];
```

And this is image storyboard image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBowW.png

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For info, you will get a much better response to your question if you include the code in-line, rather than linking it.  Also, in this case, provide details of your VC setup and the problems/errors that your code is causing.

Comment: Explain what happens with your current code and what is wrong about it

Comment: @pbasdf I edited and add the code. Wain, my code doesn't working as expected. I'm novice iOS dev and i can't figure out why that happened.

Comment: Maybe better solution will be display view controller for push notification modally?

Comment: Does this work when the app is running and active?  Does anything happen if the app is running but inactive?